# Chat reply links just broke

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The recent chat JS update (v=1843478e0f49) seems to have broken the "link my next chat message as a reply to this" arrow icon functionality.  When clicked, the icon now does nothing but emit the following error to the browser JS console:

> TypeError: e.messageId is not a function

Comparing the JS code before and after the change (which I happened to have available, since I still had an old chat tab I hadn't refreshed), the following change looks related:

```js
-  function O() {
-    var e = $(this).closest('.message').messageId(),
-    t = $('#input').focus().val().replace(/^:([0-9]+)\s+/, '');
-    r(':' + e + ' ' + t).focus()
+  function U(e) {
+    e = e || $(this).closest('message');
+    var t = e.messageId(),
+    n = $('#input').focus().val().replace(/^:([0-9]+)\s+/, '');
+    r(':' + t + ' ' + n).focus()
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, a typo where I missed the `.` in front of `message`. Oops! Fix going out in a minute.

Comment: I still cannot reply to chat messages.

Comment: @Danu Refresh your chat page and try again.

Comment: Now I feel stupid ;)